# Returning LINQ row results to Array or List

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, list

I have a LINQ query whom i want to return its rows.
the perferred output would be a list of the rows, or an array.

```
var Cases = from q in db.Cases
                    where q.Company == Company
                    select q;
```

This will get the cases i want, but i want my method to return either an array or a list of the rows.
Many google hits suggest using SelectMany(); but i keep getting errors with it.
eg :

```
public static List<string> ReceiveDBlist(string Company)
    {
        var Cases = from q in db.Cases
                    where q.Company == Company
                    select q;

        List<string> lst = Cases.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
        return lst;
    }
```

Gives this error :

> *The type arguments for method
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   System.Func>)
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.*

Sort of like this

```
0 : column1;column2;column3
1 : column1;column2;column3
2 : column1;column2;column3
```

so when i receive my list, i can disect each row, and then seperate the data.

Comment: I don't know what exactly you searched for but `SelectMany` surely is not correct here. `SelectMany` is used to flatten an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` to an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Looks like you need to project whatever `Cases` is over to a `string`. `SelectMany` will return an enumerable of whatever is in `x`, try appending another `Select` to project to a string. If all you want is a flat list of cases, then the usage of `SelectMany` is not correct, as Daniel above states, however you may still need to project using `Select` to turn a `Case` into a `string`.

Comment: the DB contains rows with Case data, like "Subject" "Status" and "Comments" etc.
The goal is the get a List with each row on each index, like i tried to explain with the columns (sorry if the description is vaque)

Comment: @SimonLausten But `Case` would be a strong type, as in a class with properties, presumably? In that case, you could just add a method to the type to format itself into a string and call `Cases.Select(case => case.ToFormattedString()).ToList()`.

Comment: Wouldn't that grab each cell 1 by one and format it to a string ?
Then the rows would be seperated, and not on each index of the list as i would like. Or am i wrong ?

Comment: @SimonLausten Without knowing more about this case type I can't see which of us is wrong. My understanding is that each case would be a "row", and that it's properties would be the cell values. My above snippet would ask the "row" to print itself out as a string and then you simply select all those strings into a list.

Comment: Ah okay, now how would i make this Method ?
string _Case = Convert.ToString(Case);
return _Case; 
Says Case is a type, but used as a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try another approach:

```
public static List<string> ReceiveDBlist(string Company)
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();

    var Cases = from q in db.Cases
                where q.Company == Company
                select q;

    foreach(var c in Cases)
    {
        string row = c.Column1 + ";" + c.Column2 + ";" + c.Column3;
        result.Add(row);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: LINQ version of the above: `return cases.Select(c => string.Join(';', new[] { c.Column1, c.Column2, c.Column3 })).ToList()`. Avoids the awkward "create-a-list-and-populate-it" code.

Answer (score 1):

That is because `Cases` is not a string, so you need to select the exact property of Cases, e.g. If you had a property `CaseTitle` you could then just use `.ToList()` like this:

```
public static List<string> ReceiveDBlist(string Company)
{
    var Cases = from q in db.Cases
                where q.Company == Company
                select q.CaseTitle;

    return Cases.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Yeah tried that as well, seemed like the simple approach, but gives this error : Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Cases_Server.Case>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'

Comment: @SimonLausten It is because Cases is not a string. I've expanded on my answer (i.e. select q.CaseTitle)

Comment: That's the problem, i want the whole row, seperated by ; or something similar. would this be possible ?

Comment: @SimonLausten What type is a `Case`?

Comment: It's my Table in the SQL server.
it's contained in the CasesDB.dbml (LINQ to SQL Classes)

Answer (score 0):

Select the data that you want in the query, and just use the `ToList` method on the query:

```
var Cases = from q in db.Cases
    where q.Company == Company
    select q.Name;

List<string> lst = Cases.ToList();
```